# How to install agda-mode on OSX El Capitan?

Tags: emacs, agda, agda-mode

I'm trying to install agda-mode on OSX. I followed the official guide (tried several others too) but can't seem to get it working.

When loading Emacs/Aquamacs I get the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/is7s/.emacs':

File error: Searching for program, no such file or directory, /bin/false

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I usually use a manually installed GHC and cabal sandboxes. But I also tried installing the Haskell Platform to make sure everything needed is in its place.

Comment: You might like [Agda Writer](https://github.com/markokoleznik/agda-writer) — an alternative to Emacs on OS X.

Comment: Disclaimer: Author of Agda Writer here. If you're not satisfied with Agda Writer, you should also check agda-mode package for Atom editor. But Agda Writer comes with compiled Agda so no installation is needed. If you have any further questions, please ask.

Comment: @markich I've tried Agda Writer when I faced this issue, but when trying to load an Agda script I got an error like "Can't load more than one file".

Comment: @is7s can you please describe in more details what have you tried to load? I would appreciate that. If you have some time to spare, you can also create a new issue on the github page.

Comment: @markich when trying to load [this](http://lpaste.net/161948) file I get the error at the bottom.

Comment: hmmm... I've copy and pasted the code and it works just fine... You did name your file as Example, right? https://snag.gy/etoaOb.jpg

Comment: @markich yes, screenshot [here](https://snag.gy/A0KWrR.jpg).

Comment: @is7s are you by any chance using Agda 2.5 or newer?

Comment: @markich yes, 2.5.1.

Comment: Then that's it! Agda >2.5 uses different library management than earlier versions. You can either use older (embedded version) or wait for me to fix the problem :) Or, of course use agda-mode for Atom or Emacs :) Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: @markich Thanks for following up. Btw how can I use the older embedded Agda?

Comment: @is7s Open up the Preferences (CMD + ,) and then make sure the checkmark at "Use Bundled Agda" is set. https://snag.gy/6LdqCE.jpg Then it should work, I hope :)

Comment: Oh, the bundled version is Agda 2.4.2.2 but I'm planning to embed the newer version as soon as I fix the problem regarding loading a file with >2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like El Captain sets the default user shell to `/bin/false` which was causing the problem. Changing it from the System Preferences to `/bin/bash` solved the issue.